# Django.. I need to have a DateField which should be updated when auth_user table gets updated

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created userprofile table. In that table, I have a field **date_updated**. my date_updated table should automatically update when auth_user table or userprofile table get update.

**Models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='userprofile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    known_languages = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, null=True)
    user_domain = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None)
```

Can any one help me?????

Comment: Doesn't `auto_now=True` what you need?

Comment: auto_now=True is not updating the data when I update the user_profile data.

Comment: Did you run makemigrations and migrate after update code?

Comment: models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

post_save signals (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-save) are one way to achieve this. They are fired after a model was changed.

Here is an example for registering a `pre_save` signal: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders (make sure to also read "Where should this code live?")

As a start, try this for your UserProfile:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils.timezone import now
from .models import UserProfile


@receiver(post_save, sender=UserProfile)
def update_date(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.date_updated = now()
    instance.save()
```

Another receiver must be registered for changes on the `User` model.